# Breadcrumbs navigation for Test catalog / test environment

Tags: visual-studio-code, testing, automated-tests, vscode-extensions, testcase

i've got a task at my job as internship to enable a breadcrumb navigation for their test catalog in vs code, which I unfortunately can't post here for security reasons.

But basically looks like this:

```
@Testcase: Prolog ; 
@setDefaultTimer(200) ; 
@abscall(..\..\..\..\.yp\test-support\versionen.kat) ; 
@abscall(..\..\..\..\.yp\test-support\bab_signaturen.kat) ; 
$BMRCONNECT: CONNECT K0 
@wait(cWaitBmsStart) ; 
$TSHARK: START xxx 
@wait(3000)

@Testcaseend
```

Problem is, we need a more detailed breadcrumb navigation which vs code don't provide. In Vs Code it's just limited to the source of the file and the file meanwhile we would like to navigate throughout the the different testcases.

I've read many informations on Vs Code's page to find some information but not of a great help. I don't know if I have to create a breadcrumb extension for the file. Can someone help?

Comment: AFAIK the breadcrumbs and OUTLINE are shown if the Language Provider implements the required Providers. Read the docs for Language Provider and look at samples.

Comment: I did but the language of the file is ".Kat" and is actually not supported by VS code.
Tried modifying the settings.json file with "files.associations": {"*.kat": "kat"} but still nothing 

plus in package.json I also tried adding in 
"contributes": {
"breadcrumbs": [
    {
       "language": "kat",
       "scheme": "file" 
    }
]

and still did not help

Comment: then you need to write a `.kat` supporting extension

Comment: That’s done too. Or maybe I should implement the breadcrumbs in the extension file?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have **Breadcrumbs** available, the language extension needs to support *Code Navigation*, specifically the `DocumentSymbolProvider`. You will know if an extension supports `DocumentSymbolProvider` if you the **Outline View** is populated. The same symbols you see there, will be in the **Breadcrumbs**.

The extension doesn't necessarily need to be a full Language Server but, at least, implements this API, providing the `Symbols` contained in a file, in order for the `breadcrumbs` to be available.

If you use the `files.associations` setting to make `.kat` files to be recognized as another file type, and this another file type has an extension that supports `DocumentSymbolProvider`, the **Outline** and the **Breadcrumbs** will work for `.kat`, otherwise, you will end up with syntax highlight only support.

BTW, Syntax Highlight (coloring the elements inside the document) and Document Symbols (Outline / Breadcrumbs) are two different things. You can create an extension that only supports Syntax Highlight with no code, simply using the TextMate support that VS Code provides. Document Symbols, on the other hand, requires some kind of implementation in order to parse the file and return the symbols and its locations. Depending on how complex is the file format, and how deep you want to go for its symbols, a simple parser with RegEx to find them would be enough for your use case.